# Excel function to cut data between to fixed character strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following text in an excel cell:

`SampleID: S-2016-011451 SubmitterID: EIROSSME    Sample Name: T1 BTMs - 6/26/16 10:00 PM    Lot Nbr:     ProductID`:

I need to cut the data so that it reads as:

T1 BTMs 6/26/16 22:00

I can format the date using text($cell,"mm/dd/yy hh:mm") but I can't get the =mid(...) to truncate the data between "Name:" and " - ".

Comment: can you hardcode the position?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
1st: =mid(B2;63;26)
2nd: =mid(B5;1;8)
3rd: =mid(B5;11;18)
4th: =concatenate(B7;B8)
```

If you want to cut between `Name:` and `-`, just use:

```
=find("Name: ";B2)
=find(" -";B2)
```

and then:

```
=mid(B2, find("Name: ";B2)+5;find(" -";B2)-find("Name: ";B2)-5)
```

I.e.:

[image]

Comment: The last line was perfect. The sample name changes so I can't hard code it, but you answered with the most flexible way possible.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTITUTE` to change, so use `SUBSTITUTE(a1,"Sample Name:","£££")` and `SUBSTITUTE(a1,"PM Lot Nbr:","$$$")` together, then you'll get £££ T1 BTM......$$$ then you can find the instances of the £££ and $$$ and mid inbetween then, or RIGHT, then LEFT

This gives you the points to cut from and to.  You can use the find of the values that we are also substituting, so find PM Lot Nbr etc.

`SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J1,"Sample Name","@@@"),"PM Lot Nbr","|||")`

Something similar to this (not complete, I shall finish and tidy)

`=MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J1,"Sample Name","@@@"),"PM Lot Nbr","|||"),LEN("@@@") + FIND("@@@",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J1,"Sample Name","@@@"),"PM Lot Nbr","|||")),(FIND("|||",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J1,"Sample Name","@@@"),"PM Lot Nbr","|||"))-FIND("@@@",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(J1,"Sample Name","@@@"),"PM Lot Nbr","|||"))-LEN("|||")))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know what to expect after `Sample Name:`
[image: MID + SUB]

1. `=MID(A1,SEARCH("Sample Name:",A1)+13,7)`
2. `=MID(A1,SEARCH(A4,A1)+LEN(A4)+3,17)`

And now you just have to convert the second cell to the date format you want (which you already know how) and concat them like `A4&C4` (if `C4` is the date after conversion).

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @Ben A Please consider marking this as the solution if it solved your problem, so it will help others ;)